# Serialize Flags enum with two equal values

Tags: c#, serialization, enums, xmlserializer, enum-flags

I want to define a flag enum like the following:

```
[Flags]
[Serializable]
public enum Numbers
{
    [XmlEnum(Name = "One")]
    One = 0x1,
    [XmlEnum(Name = "Two")]
    Two = 0x2,
    [XmlEnum(Name = "Three")]
    Three = 0x4,
    [XmlEnum(Name = "OddNumbers")]
    OddNumbers = One | Three,
    [XmlEnum(Name = "EvenNumbers")]
    EvenNumbers = Two,
    [XmlEnum(Name = "AllNumbers")]
    AllNumbers = One | Two | Three
}
```

Suppose I create an object which has a `Numbers` property and I set that property to `EvenNumbers`. Today, only `Two` is included in property, but I want to specify `EvenNumbers` so that if I add `Four` in the future it will be included in the property as well.

However, if I serialize this object using `XmlSerializer.Serialize`, the XML will say `Two` because today this is the same underlying value.

How can I force the serializer to serialize this property as `EvenNumbers`?

Answer (score 3):

Do something like that: Mark the `Number` property as `XmlIgnore` and create another property type of `string` for return the string value of enum.

```
[Serializable]
public class NumberManager
{
    [XmlIgnore]
    public Numbers Numbers { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="Numbers")]
    public string NumbersString
    {
        get { return Numbers.ToString(); }
        set { Numbers = (Numbers) Enum.Parse(typeof (Numbers), value); }
    }
}
```

Then serialize the `NumberManager`.

I hope it helps.

Comment: This was a good idea to try, but Numbers.ToString() still doesn't know which of the two enumerations was originally used to set the value. Because the underlying integer is the same for both values, I think this may be impossible. However, I wanted to check with the community before giving up.